# Save QRcode Value and Show it in another page in React Native

Tags: react-native

I wonder how I can save the value from qrcode scanner used in React Native and show the value to another page automatically. Thus, once the qrcode has been scanned, it will be redirected automatically to another page.

Is it possible to use React Navigation?

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use `react-native-qrcode-scanner` the library to create this type of functionality.

`react-native-camera` is a dependency for this package that you'll need to add to your project. To install, run the following commands:

```
npm install react-native-camera --save
react-native link react-native-camera
```

After that install and link `react-native-qrcode-scanner` by the following commands:

```
npm install react-native-qrcode-scanner --save
react-native link react-native-qrcode-scanner
react-native link react-native-permissions
```

Here is a sample code for QR scanner

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, AppRegistry, TouchableOpacity, Linking} from 'react-native';
import QRCodeScanner from 'react-native-qrcode-scanner';

export default class App extends Component {

  onSuccess(e) {
    //here you can do whatever you want to do on a successful scan
    alert(e.data);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent: 'center',}}>
        <QRCodeScanner
         showMarker={true}
         onRead={this.onSuccess.bind(this)}
       />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

If have face any difficulty in installation you can visit this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-qrcode-scanner